# What is the difference between Dagger and Dagger 2.0?

Tags: dagger, dagger-2

What is the difference between Dagger and Dagger 2.0, and why did Google decide to fork the existing project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some quotes from the [Dagger 2 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oK_XtfXPkqw)

### Issues of Dagger 1:

- Ugly generated code
- Runtime graph composition
- Inefficient graph creation
- Partial traceability
- Map-like API

### Dagger 2 solutions:

- Compile-time validation of the **entire** graph
- Easy debugging; entirely concrete call stack for provision *and*
  creation
- Fully traceable
- POJO API
- Performance

### Dagger 2 issues:

- Less flexible
- No dynamism
- No automated migration path from Guice

Answer (score 0):

**Dagger 1.0**

- Some Reflection APIs are used for code generation.
- Reflection is slow.
- Exceptions are not captured at compile time.

**Dagger 2.0**

- Use the annotation processor for code generation at build time.
- The annotation processor is fast.
- Exceptions get captured at compile-time only.

Answer (score 0):

**Dagger1.x**: It is a runtime dependency injection framework created by Square. Which is reflection based solution that connect dependencies at runtime. Now it is deprecated in favour of Google's Dagger2.

useful links:
https://github.com/square/dagger
https://square.github.io/dagger/

some disadvantages are:

- uses slow Reflection API, which is even slower in Android
- Performance overhead
- less traceable and runtime graph composition

**Dagger2.x**: It is an adaptation of an earlier version created by Square and now maintained by Google. Dagger2 is compile time Dependency injection framework that generates code to connect dependencies at compile time.

Advantages of Dagger2:

- no more Reflection API
- better generated code as hand written, so more traceable.
- improves performance by nearly 10 times faster than Dagger1.
- requires less configuration for Modules

some useful links for Dagger2:
https://github.com/google/dagger
https://dagger.dev/

If you are still using dagger1, here is the migration guide from dagger1 to dagger2 https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/dagger-1-migration.html